# Self sizing cells with three UILabels not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

This is the `UITableViewCell` I have:

[image: cell]

The three `UILabel`s have `trailing`, `top`, `bottom` and `leading` constraints.

- This is the hugging priority and compression resistance priority for the `UILabel` Name:

[image: name priority]

- This is the hugging priority and compression resistance priority for the `UILabel` Location:

[image: location priority]

- This is the hugging priority and compression resistance priority for the `UILabel` Type:

[image: type priority]

On the `viewDidLoad` from my `UITableViewController` I'm doing something like this:

```
 self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
 self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 self.tableView.reloadData()
```

But when I run the app, the `UITableViewCell`s don't self sizing:

[image: result]

What am I doing wrong or what do I need to do to make the `UITableViewCell`s make them self sizing?

**Edit**

I set to 0 the `numberOfLines` for each `UILabel`, now the location `UILabel` doesn't appear

Comment: The vertical hugging priority of the Location UILabel is 1 less than the others, mind explaining why you did that?

Comment: @Z.Hung It worked for me in another project but I don't know how to make it work in a new project

Comment: Have you tried to just change the hugging priority to make them all the same?

Comment: @Z.Hung yes and I got xcode errors about the priority

Comment: You should increase the `Content hugging priority vertical` to 751, not the resistance

Comment: @Tj3n I set it and it still not working

Comment: Do you have vertical spacing between the 3 labels or do you have constraints to `contentView`.

Comment: @Sulthan the three labels have vertical spacing between them

Comment: Your vertical `contentHuggingPriority` and `contentCompressionResistance` should be probably set to `1000` (required). Also make sure there is no `bottom` constraint for the image. Also consider returning `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` from `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely that your Text turned out larger in runtime causing the total height in your cell View to turn out greater than the row height itself.

First equate all the hugging priority and then try changing the spacing distance between the Labels with the relation 'Greater than or Equal' and then set the constant to something small like zero. If you still get a constraint error, increase your tableView row height.

Alternative method:
Add all 3 UILabels into another UIView with spacing zero between them, do not set a height constraint for this UIView and just set it in the centerY of the cellView and spaced from the ImageView

Tip: Only change constraint priorities if your UI is what you want even after the constraints are broken, unless of course you know what you're doing

Answer (score 1):

For ur case no need to vertical hugging priority,just give

label.numberOfLines = 0

that works fine.

Comment: I set `numberOfLines` to 0 in all `UILabel`s and now the location `UILabel` doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

The question says you want to resize the label, but based on your code it seems like you want to do it by resizing the tableview rows. If that's the case, the correct place to set row height in a tableView is:

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 80

}
```

Where "return 80" means you want table rows to be of height 80. Please let me know if I didn't understand your question right.

Comment: This is not worked for me because I want the `UITableViewCell` will be self sizing

Answer (score -1):

The label doesn't work because the storyboard is not very useful.

Set the `var`:

```
var imageView: UIImageView ={
let image = UIImageView()
image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
return image
}()

var textView: UITextView ={
let text = UITextView()
text.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
return text
}()
```

And you continue with other label.

You have to set constraints like this example:

```
self.addSubview(imageView)
self.addSubview(textView)

imageView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).active=true
imageView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.leftAnchor, constant:-10).active=true
imageView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(70).active=true
imageView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(70).active=true

label.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.topAnchor, constant: -5).active=true
label.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(imageView.rightAnchor, constant: 3).active=true
label.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.widthAnchor, constant -70).active=true
label.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(30).active=true

label2.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(label.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).active=true
label2.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(imageView.rightAnchor, constant: 3).active=true
label2.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.widthAnchor, constant -70).active=true
label2.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(30).active=true
```

And with this way also for the third label.

Comment: But I'm not using any `UITextView`

Comment: @pableiros i have updated the answer, it is the same thing with labels.